# Why is asciidoc giving the error "manpage document title is mandatory"?

Tags: manpage, asciidoc

When trying to generate a man page with asciidoc, like this:

```
a2x -v -f manpage  foobar.1.txt
```

I get the error `manpage document title is mandatory`.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of `=`s under the man page title at the top of the file has to be of the same length as the line above it.  This will cause the error:

```
FOO-BAR-QUUX(1)
========
```

This will fix it:

```
FOO-BAR-QUUX(1)
===============
```